# OpenAm doesn't create users when OAuth authentication enabled

Tags: openam

I have two instancies of OpanAM. One works as OAuth2 provider, the second works as OAuth2 client.

When I enable option "Map to anonymous user" on service instance, all flow works fine - client redirects me to provider, where I enter my username and password, then it redirects me back to client where I can see my new anonimous profile.

But in my case I need to map user from provider to client when user logins to my system.
When i enable function "Create account if it does not exist" when I apply consent screen it redirects me back to client and I see this error message: "Unknown error. Please contact your Administrator".

I have enabled logs and in logs I see this error:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["sub"] not found.
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["name"] not found.
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["given_name"] not found.
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["family_name"] not found.
ERROR: unknown callback null
```

When I perform REST-request to provider on userinfo endpoint with Postman it returns me this JSON:

```
{
"sub": "user123",
"name": "name",
"given_name": "gn",
"family_name": "fn"
}
```

Based on this response, I configure mapping in OAuth2 module on client OpenAM this way:

Account Mapper Configuration:

```
sub=sub 
name=name 
given_name=given_name 
family_name=family_name
```

Attribute Mapper Configuration:

```
sub=sub 
name=name 
given_name=given_name 
family_name=family_name
```

Thanks!

Comment: As always , please provide the OpenAM fork your are using as there are several projects which forked the ForgeRock code.

Comment: I use OpenAM 14.6.2 Build d3c90af2bd (2021-February-08 15:11)
which I downloaded from this official github: https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM
This OpenAM version I use as provider and as client/

Comment: Sorry, do u have any idea?

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr
The problem was in "Prompt for password setting and activation code" checkbox on client side. But now, when provider redirects me back to client, client creates user but username and Last Name look like this: cca93662-ceb6-41d6-a7a3-cb5982d110a3

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr How does client gets attributes to map account? Does it do it with userinfo endpoint?

Comment: According to the code it uses 'UserInfo' request/response when a value for `User Profile Service URL` is set. If this is not the case the claims from the Id Tokens are used.